# Flask route running code before redirect and throwing error in python console but not in flask debug

Tags: python, flask

I have a strange problem where the python terminal is throwing an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'` but I **do not receive** any error in the Flask debug console and the **app works as it should**, without any problems. The error in python console is driving me nuts and I'd like to understand what is happening.

The layout of my app is as follows. I render a homepage which retrieves input from the user via an html form and takes that value, a stock ticker in this case, and redirects to the function infoPage where the stock ticker is used to perform some web scraping.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def stockTickerInput():
    if request.method == "POST":
        ticker = request.form['ticker'].upper()
        return redirect(url_for('infoPage', ticker=ticker))
    return render_template('home.html')
```

For some reason, python is running this code prior to flask redirecting to `infoPage`. I know this because as soon as `home.html` is rendered I receive the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'` before the user even enters a stock ticker in the html form.

```
@app.route('/<ticker>')
def infoPage(ticker):     
    # scrapes stock chart/company info from finviz
    def stockInfo():        
        url = 'https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=' + ticker
        html = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
        
        # finds news table within finviz website
        stock_website = soup.find('table', class_="fullview-title")
        company_name = stock_website.find('a', class_='tab-link').text
        
        return company_name
    
    # functions to be passed as variables in jinja2 template
    info = stockInfo()
    
    return render_template('stockInfo.html', ticker=ticker, info=info)
```

**traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JGrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\JGrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\JGrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\JGrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\JGrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\JGrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\JGrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\JGrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\JGrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\JGrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\JGrov\Google Drive\GitHub\flask_stockinfo\app.py", line 149, in infoPage
    info = stockInfo(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\JGrov\Google Drive\GitHub\flask_stockinfo\app.py", line 42, in stockInfo
    company_name = stock_website.find('a', class_='tab-link').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I would be very thankful to any insight on why this is happening.

Comment: You need to show the traceback if you get get one. Also, **never** use bare `except:`. It will hide whatever exception happens.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I've added a copy of the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This portion:

```py
if result is None:  # if result is none means ticker exists
    return redirect(url_for('infoPage', ticker=ticker))
```

of you code executes because `result` gets a value of None from this line:

```py
result = match.find('h4').text
```

hence, fires the `return redirect(url_for('infoPage', ticker=ticker))` ever before your `return render_template('stockInfo.html', ticker=ticker, info=info)` runs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I understand what you are saying. I've edited my code in the original post but I keep receiving the same error. Is it possible to only redirect to infoPage only after the user submits the form? From my understanding, all the functions are being processed when the page loads and I'm receiving the attribute error because stockInfo is expecting a value and not a 'NoneType'.

Comment: The `ticker` parameter should be parsed into `stockInfo` function and not `infoPage`. Then you can call the function like this: `stockInfo(ticker)`. Prior to this, the user input received from the submitted form should have parsed into the `ticker` variable. (ensure its scope is not local)

Comment: the scope was the issue. Thanks for pointing that out